# Jquery - $.When not trigger ajax on done menthod

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Was try to implement another ajax call based on the first two results with Jquery $.When method. Basically, all three Ajax will populate a carousel on the page based on the results. Therefore I choose $.When for continuous checking.  But the third Ajax which under Done() method is not called even there was no result from above two APIs or with initial values zero(0). Not sure if I missed anything!

**jQuery:**

```
let itemCat1Count = 0;
let itemCat2Count = 0;

$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: "/webmethod/GetItemsCatOne",
        type: "POST",
        data: '',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof (data.ResponseObject) !== undefined && data.ResponseObject !== null) {
                itemCat1Count = data.ResponseObject.Items.length;
                // carousel inital codes
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {}
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: "/webmethod/GetItemsCatTwo",
        type: "POST",
        data: '',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof (data.ResponseObject) !== undefined && data.ResponseObject !== null) {
                itemCat2Count = data.ResponseObject.Items.length;
                // carousel inital codes
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {}
    }),
).done(function (xhrSavedRings, xhrShoppingBagItems) {
    if (itemCat1Count == 0 && itemCat2Count == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/webmethod/GetItemsSpecial",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (jObject) {
                console.log(jObject);
                // carousel inital codes
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {}
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you pass your if condition? Try without condition

Comment: try putting `console` statements in `error` handlers of first 2 ajax. Also didn't get your `if(itemCat1Count == 0 && itemCat2Count == 0)` check. Did you mean that both ajax will return objects with 0 item?

Comment: This is a very obvious mistake in how to use `$.when()`. `$.when()` requires promises as arguments. `$.when` does not have the powers to know when functions you passing are done or completed. All these ajax calls functions have to return promises that are resolved. After that `.done` will be called. Read more here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @vijayP purpose is to, if there was no item return from first two then call third.

Comment: @DanielSmith Did my solution / answer solved your question ? Please mark my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as accepted for this if it worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Few things to highlight - `$.when()` requires promises as arguments. `$.when` does not have the powers to know when functions you passing are done or completed
From the official documentation of `$.when` You have return promises or return something from your ajax calls.

Here what its says => In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to `jQuery.when()`, the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed.

I have assigned a retrun value from each `$.ajax` call you are making. $.when will know check if there is something coming from return and is resolved then it will go to `.done`

Run snippet below to see the console log on `.done`

```js
let itemCat1Count = 0;
let itemCat2Count = 0;

function first() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/webmethod/GetItemsCatOne",
    type: "POST",
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
      if (typeof(data.ResponseObject) !== undefined && data.ResponseObject !== null) {
        console.log(data.ResponseObject.Items.length)
        itemCat1Count = data.ResponseObject.Items.length;
        // carousel inital codes
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {}
  });
}

function second() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/webmethod/GetItemsCatTwo",
    type: "POST",
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
      if (typeof(data.ResponseObject) !== undefined && data.ResponseObject !== null) {
        itemCat2Count = data.ResponseObject.Items.length;
        // carousel inital codes
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {}
  });
}

$.when.apply(first(), second()).done(function() {
  console.log("First and Second is done running - I am from done");
  if (itemCat1Count == 0 && itemCat2Count == 0) {
     return $.ajax({
      url: "/webmethod/GetItemsSpecial",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(jObject) {
        console.log(jObject);
        // carousel inital codes
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {}
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```